# Which dependencies are added to a Gradle project which uses a 'project lib dependency' and is this configurable?

Tags: gradle

Gradle [project lib dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies) are a means of defining a project as requiring, as one of its dependencies, the output from another project.

The documentation states:

> A “lib” dependency is a special form of an execution dependency. It
> causes the other project to be built first and adds the jar with the
> classes of the other project to the classpath. It also adds the
> dependencies of the other project to the classpath.

However, *which* dependencies of the project are added?  Is it the `compile`, `implementation` or `runtime` dependencies, for instance?  Is this configurable?  i.e. how would I configure a project to require the output of another project and the dependencies from an arbitrary configuration of that other project?

For instance, in my root project, I can define `project1` to depend on `project2`:

```
project(":project1") {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':project2')
    }
}
```

How do I add the dependencies of an arbitrary configuration of `:project2` (let's say it's called `myConfiguration`) to `project1`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is contained within the DSL documentation for [`Dependencyhandler`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html).

> By default, when you declare dependency to projectA, you actually
> declare dependency to the 'default' configuration of the projectA. If
> you need to depend on a specific configuration of projectA, use map
> notation for projects:

```
configurationName project(path: ':projectA', configuration: 'someOtherConfiguration')
```